How to have split files inherit their parents style?
I want to generate a separate file for each polygon in a layer of 1,000 polygons and for each of those layers to inherit the style settings of the parent. Is this possible?

You can copy a style using the right button click menu on your parent layer and apply it to your selected layers.  You could instead save your parent layer's style to a qml file and apply that to your selected/grouped layers.  There'a also a plugin (MultiQML) that  you could use.

Thanks John but both those techniques don't imbed the style with the layer i.e. if I forward the layer to another QGIS users, the parent style is only recognised in the .qgz file not the .gkpg file.
I'll look into the multiqml plugin now

You can save style with your features in database (in this case .gpkg file). Right click on layer, Export -> Save as QGIS Layer Style File and from drop-down Save style menu chose In datasource database.
